# How can I remove dead code in Angular Universal server bundle?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Recently I have been working a lot with Angular Universal and I stumbled upon this problem which I cannot seem to solve.

I noticed that whenever I build my server side bundle by using the following command: `npm run build:ssr`, my generated server bundle containing the main.js file is huge (over 5mb).

I did my own research on this and I generated the source maps for the server bundle build as you can see below:

[image]

As you can immediately notice, the node_modules packages contain most of the size taken in my bundle. It seems like the packages are being imported as a whole and no tree shaking is being done to remove dead code. For instance ng-bootstrap was imported as a whole resulting in around 267kb, when in reality I only used a few modules in my app. Same as fortawesome package.

Strangely enough, when I check the source maps for my browser bundle (client app), it seems like there is tree shaking being applied and only the relevant modules are being included in the final bundle. Below is the source map of my browser build showing ng-bootstrap as [42.6KB] and fortawesome as [41.19KB]:

[image]

If it helps, I will also post the server build angular.json section:

```
"server": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
    "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "src/assets/js/custom-webpack.config.js",
        "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
    },
    "outputPath": "dist/proxykingdom-spa/server",
    "main": "server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
    "production": {
        "outputHashing": "media",
        "fileReplacements": [
        {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "optimization": true,
        "extractLicenses": true
    }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
}
```

As a side note, I created a brand new angular universal project using their ng schematics, installed ng-bootstrap and imported a single module. I could reproduce the same behaviour immediately.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to apply tree shaking and remove dead code in the server build in Angular SSR? Am I getting this all wrong?

Thanks for the time spent to read this thread.

Comment: I think tree shaking is applied, but the server side bundle also contains a compiler which probably is just a lot of code.

Comment: Yes it does, in fact a brand new project from scratch without any dependencies results in a bundle of over 3mb. However it still doesn't explain how certain packages get imported as a whole. There is a big difference in size between server import deps and client import deps. It's like not removing dead code but rather just importing everything as highlighted in my screenshots.

Comment: I suspect that server side rendering allows for templates that could be using packages, so it might not know beforehand if it can be removed, if you load a dynamic template from a database. Perhaps you are not doing that, but it may allow it. I don't know enough about the features to answer it. I'm just guessing.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am just going through the same problem and so far, nothing has worked.